# variables in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've gotten very confused by the way variables in rails are referenced and/or assigned some values.

Could anyone tell me the meaning of the following lines/statements?

(I come from the C-world, and I'm having a 'very' hard time wrapping my head around Ruby/Rails syntax)

<1>
Are we declaring `:name` and `:email` as variables here?
Also, why is there a `colon` in front of `name` and `email`?

```
attr_accessible :name, :email
```

<2> Assigning to variable
From the example above, if `name` and `email` were variables, how do I set a value to them?

```
def foo
  name = 'New Name'
end
```

Or

```
def foo
  :name => 'New Name'
end
```

?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your `first` and `second`. I appreciate the comments, but I really don't see how that answers my questions

Answer (score 0):

In Rails you use a ORM that extracts field names from your table, for example if you have a table `items`:

```
|id | name    |
|1  | a string|
```

You will have `class Item`, and let's say an instance `item`, then you have access to:

```
item.id      # -> 1
item.name    # -> a string
```

According to your examples:

```
def foo
  name = 'New Name'  # You are not setting the variable, you are creating a local variable called name
  # To set variable
  self.name = 'a name'
end
```

Or

```
def foo
  :name => 'New Name' # you are returning a hash, but you are lacking brackets, not setting a variable
end
```

The line `attr_accessible :name, :email` allows you to do this:

```
Item.new({
  name: 'asd',
  email: 'sad'
})
```

If you don't add `:email` in `attr_accessible`, for example, the previous would raise a warning, something like:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: email
```

This is useful when you receive params in controller like:

```
Item.new(params[:item])
```

See that params, is a hash, you can see it in rails server console.

Comment: And this line is declaring two variables? `attr_accessible :name, :email` ?

Comment: is not, is allowing you to set name and email with this call Item.new(a_hash_here)

Comment: So how do I declare an instance variable in a Rail/Ruby object?

Comment: with @my_var inside any method

Comment: If I do `@my_var` inside a method called `foo`, would it be visible to some method called `bar`?

Comment: Is there any difference between `@my_var` and `self.my_var`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25381/discussion-between-juanpastas-and-one-two-three)

Comment: (Sorry, it might be a bit too late to join this discussion now, but I got caught up in other stuff... didn't notice this)
I didn't meant the question mark to be part of self.my_var
the question was is there any diffeerece between @my_var and self.my_var
It seems to me that self is the same thing as this in Java
Is the the correct analogy?